# How to set my DNS record to farward to a other domain?

Tags: dns

I have a DNS record like this:

[image]

Now I want to redirect all requests to a subdomain like:

```
http://myExampleBlog.wordpress.com/
```

How must the DNS Record look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myExampleBlog.wordpress.com   CNAME      yourdomain.com
```

You better use [Map an Existing Domain](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/)

Comment: But I does only have access to the DNS of yourdomain.com and not to wordpress.com, does it work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

May be what Avin meant was the opposite of what he wrote.

```
www.yourdomain.com CNAME myExampleBlog.wordpress.com
```

but for the root (naked) domain you can not add a CNAME record, so you will have to ask the support of the DNS host, if you can create a web redirection, so it will be like this

```
yourdomain WR www.yourdomain.com
```

It will redirect to the www subdomain, which is an alias of the blog domain.

Regards,
Lanex